# How to extract data using WordPress API?

Tags: wordpress

I want to extract some info from the WordPress plugin page. For example I am interested in getting the 'tags' from a plugins page and saving them locally. I have read it is possible using the Plugins API - http://api.wordpress.org/plugins/info/1.0/. But have no idea how to go about it.

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

A Simple request to http://api.wordpress.org/plugins/info/1.0/PLUGIN_NAME
will return all of the plugin data you can access using this API

and if you want you can add format as suffix to the url

- JSON - http://api.wordpress.org/plugins/info/1.0/PLUGIN_NAME.json XML
- XML - http://api.wordpress.org/plugins/info/1.0/PLUGIN_NAME.XML